Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants SDK - Report error while trying to use File Retrieval Tool
It is about creating Assistant using chatGPT model. I use Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants SDK.
While trying to create an assistant using below code,  it reports OpenAI Retrieval V1 tool is not supported, in favor of the more advanced v2 file_search tool.
Code Snippet:
AssistantCreationOptions aco = new AssistantCreationOptions(modelName);

aco.Tools.Add(new RetrievalToolDefinition());

aco.FileIds.AddRange(fileIds);   // This the list of files uploaded by the user i.e framework details file

aco.Instructions  = "Summarize the framework details in 10 lines";

Assistant assistant = await client?.CreateAssistantAsync(aco);

Exact error is given below
Azure OpenAI Retrieval v1 tool is not supported in favor of the more advanced v2 file_search tool. Please use \`file_search\` in the v2 api.

I need to know how to use file_search option

The error says Retrieval v1 is not supported. Instead of that use file search check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/file-search?view=azure-node-preview&tabs=python#file-search-support

Thank you Jayashankar, I would like to get this done through Azure.AI.OpenAI sdk as I use c# as programming language and the feature that I am building will be integrated with the existing asp.net core based web application.   Is there a way to mention AOI version in the SDK, I referred the MS document but there is mention of it.

You will need to use the latest version of Azure.AI.OpenAI Nuget package (2.1.0-beta.1 at the time of writing this answer).
You will then create a new instance of AzureOpenAIClient. Using this, you can then work with the latest version of Assistants API.
Here's a sample code to create an assistant:
var client = new AzureOpenAIClient(new Uri("endpoint"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var assistant = (await client.GetAssistantClient().CreateAssistantAsync(_chatCompletionAIConnectionSettings.DeploymentId, new AssistantCreationOptions()
            {
                Name = assistantName,
                Tools = { ToolDefinition.CreateFileSearch(), ToolDefinition.CreateCodeInterpreter() },
                ToolResources = 
                { 
                    FileSearch = new FileSearchToolResources()
                    {
                        NewVectorStores = { new VectorStoreCreationHelper("list of file ids")}
                    } 
                },
                Instructions = "You are a helpful assistant that answer user queries from the attached documents. "
            })).Value;


Thanks Gaurav.   I use 2.0.0-beta.2 and this issue exist.

Trying changing RetrievalToolDefinition with FileSearchTool.

Also, in the new SDK things work differently. You will need to upload a file, attach it to a vector store and then associate that vector store with your assistant.

FileSearchTool exist in OpenAI.Assistants SDK,   It is not available in Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants.   Using Azure.AI.OpenAI I could upload a file, but feed that file into into RetrievalTool is the actual issue.   unless I create RetrievalTool I can provide vector store id details.      any sample code using Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants Api to create a assistant with the both tool Codeinterpretor and RetrievalToolDefinition with providing existing vector store info would really  help.

You should not be using Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants (this is the mistake I made :)). I wish they have better documentation.

Updated the code in my answer. HTH.

AssistantCreationOptions aco = new AssistantCreationOptions(modelName);
aco.Tools.Add(new CodeInterpreterToolDefinition());
aco.Tools.Add(new RetrievalToolDefinition());
aco.FileIds.AddRange(fileIds);  // internal framework document file id reference
aco.Instructions = "Explain how error is handled in the framework"
var assistantResponse = await client?.CreateAssistantAsync(aco);   This throws the error mentioned in my question

Have you tried my code?

Please note I am connecting a model deployed in Azure OpenService Service Platform. I tried to connect this model using OpenAI. Assistants SDK it did not work.  got  http error 404 while tried to create openAI.Assistants

My code connects to Azure OpenAI only. There is no need to use OpenAI. Assistants SDK as Azure.AI.OpenAI has assistants functionality.

Thanks a ton, the code you have given helped to solve the issue.  The big mistake was having both Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistants and OpenAI. Assistants installed.  I stopped using Azure.AI.OpenAI.Assistant as per your advice.
